# Performance Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer, latency

I have written an code in Hyperledger Composer Playground and now I want to find out, how the performance (computing power, latency, responce time) of my program is.
Is there any way to get this information in Hyperledger Composer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test this directly in Composer, but Hyperledger has a dedicated project for benchmarking: [Caliper](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/caliper). Caliper allows you to get statistics regarding a number of performance indicators, such as TPS (Transactions Per Second), transaction latency, resource utilisation and more.